# How to prevent Google sheets from rounding large integers in calculations

Tags: google-sheets

Whenever I try to perform a calculation with a large number result,

> 26^14

spreadsheets automatically rewrite it in scientific notation, not saving the excluded numbers and cutting it off.

> 6.451E+19

To get around this, I have to manually type in the answer.

> 64509974703297150976

This works for displaying the number, but whenever I try to multiply this number in another cell, sheets will perform the calculation on the rounded number form of the scientific notation number.

> 64509974703297200000 * 2 = 129019949406594000000

This is the number I get instead of the desired:

> 64509974703297150976 * 2 = 129019949406594301952

Exact numbers are required and this is just getting really frustrating. I would really like to have the answer to stop google sheets from doing this as soon as possible (duh).

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/602810/how-can-i-use-extremely-large-numbers-in-my-spreadsheet-programs

Answer (score 3):

Since Google Sheets use JavaScript, you may copy a library and use it.

Here is the link to library with description on how to use:

https://github.com/peterolson/BigInteger.js

## Step 1

Go here and copy the code into your Script Editor:
https://github.com/peterolson/BigInteger.js/blob/master/BigInteger.min.js

## Step 2

Write your own custom function like this:

```
function bigIntPow(a, b)
{
  return bigInt(a).pow(b).toString(); 
}
```

## Step 3

Use the function from Sheet:

`=bigIntPow(26,14)`

The result is text: `64509974703297150976`